# Find location of objects in PDF iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pdf, cgpdf

I have a PDF that is structured like this:

```
 ________________________________________________________
|                                |                      |
| 1. This is a simple question   |  A  B  C  D  E  F  G |
|________________________________|______________________|
|                                |                      |
| 2. Another simple question     |  A  B  C  D  E  F  G |
|________________________________|______________________|

... all the way to the end of the page.
```

The user fills out this question air in the app and when they are finished it needs to print out the PDF question air with the selected "A, B, C, D, E, F, G" with circle drawn around them.

I can load a PDF and add annotations to it fine but the problem is that I have no idea how to find the coordinates of "A, B, C, D, E, F, G" to draw the circle around it. Is there anyway to programmatically figure this out? My last resort would be to open it up in a UIImageView and draw all the circles there but that will cut the resolution down significantly which isn't good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was not able to find an easy way to find the coordinates of "A B C.." for each question in the PDF so I,

1. Added a transparent view
2. Added to UISteppers, one for X and Y
3. Added a label to view to display an (x,y)
4. Drew a circle with `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData`
5. Painstakingly used the steppers to move the circle around the PDF to each "A B C.." while taking note of the coordinates.

Definitely not the most elegant solution but programmers can't always be clever I'm afraid. Only took around and hour to finish (for 30 questions).

Comment: doesn't your UI view draw the A,B,C,D...? And in that case why could you not draw them in the PDF without resorting to fixed values?

Comment: Because the user never sees the existing questionnaire PDF, see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be going about this the wrong way. Since the user is filling out the questionaire in the app you are able to "draw" the views with the circles around each selected letter. When you export your PDF have your view draw using a PDF Context.

Here is some partial code to get you started:

```
- (NSData) renderViewToPDF:(UIView*)view
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSDictionary  *pdfOptions = @{...};

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, _pageRect, pdfOptions);

    [questionaireView drawRect:questionaireView.bounds];

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    return pdfData;
}
```

After a call to this method all you need to do is write the data to a file. As for the drawing of the circles, if you are using bezier paths they are vector based and thus resolution independent.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am able to draw onto the PDF fine. My problem was is that I did not know the coordinates of the "A B C D.." for each question. I was wondering if there was a way to find them in the pdf tree(?) somehow. I figured it out though (the hard way).

Comment: In your app, doesn't your view draw the A,B,C... for the user to select? If so how does your app know where to write A,B,C...? Or is the original questionaire also a PDF?

Comment: The app is an adaption of the existing PDF questionnaire, so it doesn't directly use the PDF until the end and the user wants to email the results to someone.

Comment: So that means that in your app you are drawing a UIView with text labels, the letters A,B,C,D... for the user to choose and all? Unless there is something that I'm missing?

Comment: I have built out a the entire survey natively. So the questions are presented and the user selects the answers in a UITableView. The PDF drawing all happens in the background when the user wants to email the results the someone. It takes all the answers and transfers them the existing PDF questionnaire.